# How to populate JTextArea with file from JList

Tags: java, swing, file-io, textarea, jlist

Im creating an application that gets a list of .java and .class files from a chosen directory and places them in a JList. I am using Netbeans 7.1.2.

I have all the files being displaying in the JList like i want, what i cant seem to do is to open open the selected .java file in the jTextArea.

I need to get the file from the JList to pass it into the JTextArea but it is not working

```
     try
     {
         FileReader reader= new FileReader( jlist.getSelectedValue() );
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( reader);
         textarea.read( br );
         br.close();
         textarea.requestFocus();               
     } 
     catch(Exception e2) {}
```

Does anybody see where im going wrong?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `read(...)` method passing in a BufferedFileReader not the `write(...)` method if you are to read a file into a JTextArea. This should make sense to you since your goal here is to read, not to write.

Comment: I have edited my code, is that what you are saying i have to do?

Comment: yes, but don't call `textarea.setText("")` or else you'll erase what you just loaded into the `JTextArea` :)

Comment: @newSpringer: try it and see what happens. But as others have told you, do not ignore exceptions else you be flying blind.

Comment: @newSpringer: Yep, I knew you could do it! Congratulations!!

Answer (score 0):

```
textarea.write( bw );
```

Does this compile? write method seems to be meant for writing contents of textarea to a file not the other way around.

Also if something goes wrong, make sure not to catch the exception and ignore it. The exception trace can be very helpful in understanding what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble, you should be displaying/logging your exceptions, not swallowing them quietly.  Your code could be encountering a problem that has a helpful exception  associated with it, but you won't know until you write code that tells you about exceptions.

You could start with this:

```
try
{
     File file = (File)jlist.getSelectedValue();
     FileReader reader = new FileReader( file );
     textarea.read( br );
     br.close();
     textarea.requestFocus(); 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
}
```

Comment: i have it printing out an exception in my code but i didnt add it to this code as i just wanted to show that it is inside a try-catch. the error do is because the reader is trying to read an object that is coming from the jlist and not a file... do not do why as i have added a list<file> to the jlist

Comment: Do you see an error message printed?  What is the exact text of the error message?  Can you copy and paste it?  Try casting the return value of `getSelectedValue()` to `File` (I show this in my answer.)

Comment: fixed my other error, just got this one now 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: null (The system cannot find the file specified)'

Comment: It probably means jlist.getSelectedValue() is returning null.  Make sure you click to select something in the list before you run the method which tries to open the selected item.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you add something to a JList - A visual component - It's not longer a List of objects, as such. You just have an array with index 0 to n which you can pick from, but nothing is really IN them. What you COULD do would be make an array of Files (new File[]) and store all files in there so you can access them at any time.